# How to align four Author names in the IEEE conference format

Tags: ieeeconf, nameauth

so I am new to LaTeX and I wanted to know if it was possible to align 4 author names in an IEEE conference format. I read about the command \linebreakand but I don't think it worked the right way. I wish for the names to appear in the following order from left to right for each roww

1. First author - Charu Jain
2. Second Author Surya Sashank
3. Third Author - Venkateswaran
4. Fourth Author - marrkandan

I tried the following code but the names were coming up misaligned. If you could please guide me and also let me know as to what else I need to mention in my question so that you could answer it better.[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
    \makeatletter
\newcommand{\linebreakand}{%
  \end{@IEEEauthorhalign}
  \hfill\mbox{}\par
  \mbox{}\hfill\begin{@IEEEauthorhalign}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\title{Low-cost BLE based Indoor Localization using RSSI Fingerprinting and Machine Learning}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Charu Jain}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Electronics and Communication Department} \\
\textit{Sri Sivasubramanya Nadar College of Engineering}\\
Kalavakkam, India\\
charu18033@ece.ssn.edu.in}
%
\and
%
\IEEEauthorblockN{Gundepudi V Surya Sashank}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Mechanical Department} \\
\textit{Sri Sivasubramanya Nadar College of Engineering}\\
Kalavakkam, India \\
gundepudi18047@mech.ssn.edu.in}
%
\linebreakand
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN
{Venkateswaran. N}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Electronics and Communication Department} \\
\textit{Sri Sivasubramanya Nadar College of Engineering}\\
Kalavakkam, India \\
venkateswarann@ssn.edu.in}
%
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{S. Markkandan}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Electronics and Communication Department} \\
\textit{Anand Institute of Higher Technology}\\
Kazhipattur, India \\
markkandans.ece@aiht.ac.in}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%modify your code to: 
 \makeatletter

\newcommand{\newlineauthors}{%
\end{@IEEEauthorhalign}\hfill\mbox{}\par
\mbox{}\begin{@IEEEauthorhalign}}  

\makeatother
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please do not only post an code snippet, explain what it does and show an compilable code with it for a fast proof. Then you made your answer to be a valid answer ...

Answer (score 0):

You only need to remove the `\and` after `\linebreakand`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
    \makeatletter
\newcommand{\linebreakand}{%
  \end{@IEEEauthorhalign}
  \hfill\mbox{}\par
  \mbox{}\hfill\begin{@IEEEauthorhalign}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\title{Low-cost BLE based Indoor Localization using RSSI Fingerprinting and Machine Learning}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Charu Jain}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Electronics and Communication Department} \\
\textit{Sri Sivasubramanya Nadar College of Engineering}\\
Kalavakkam, India\\
charu18033@ece.ssn.edu.in}
%
\and
%
\IEEEauthorblockN{Gundepudi V Surya Sashank}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Mechanical Department} \\
\textit{Sri Sivasubramanya Nadar College of Engineering}\\
Kalavakkam, India \\
gundepudi18047@mech.ssn.edu.in}
%
\linebreakand
%\and <------------------------ REMOVED
\IEEEauthorblockN
{Venkateswaran. N}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Electronics and Communication Department} \\
\textit{Sri Sivasubramanya Nadar College of Engineering}\\
Kalavakkam, India \\
venkateswarann@ssn.edu.in}
%
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{S. Markkandan}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Electronics and Communication Department} \\
\textit{Anand Institute of Higher Technology}\\
Kazhipattur, India \\
markkandans.ece@aiht.ac.in}
}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, as usual here, give an short compilable TeX code for an fast proof!

Comment: I've updated your post with a complete example of what you suggested. This is not entirely accurate as the horizontal alignment between the top and bottom row is off slightly.